# Using urllib.request.urlopen to get JSON data

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

I am trying to use an api to get some data about the prices of cryptocurrencies on an exchange site. When using urllib.request.urlopen, I keep getting errors.

```
import urllib
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request
import urllib.error
import json


def coin_price(coin):
    url = 'https://yobit.net/api/3/ticker/'
    pair = coin + '_btc'
    final_url = url + pair
    obj = urllib.request.urlopen(final_url)
    jsonobj = obj.read().decode('utf-8')
    data = json.loads(jsonobj)
    item = data['ticker']

    final = item['last']
    print(final)

coin_price("ltc")
```

These are the errors I am getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/x/Downloads/PycharmProjects/test.py", line 20, in <module>
coin_price("ltc")

File "C:/Users/x/Downloads/PycharmProjects/test.py", line 12 incoin_price
obj = urllib.request.urlopen(final_url)

File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36  32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 223, in urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)

File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 532, in open
response = meth(req, response)

File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 642, in http_response
'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)

File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 650, in http_error_default
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Comment: I see no error mentioned in the question (at least not error output). So maybe you missed something. Read the rules please. This is also such a basic task, that there are plenty of examples around.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Please give the error raised.

Comment: I added the errors

Comment: Did you check the URL you're trying to access? 
Here is the result I got from  https://yobit.net/api/3/ticker/_btc: {"success":0,"error":"Invalid pair name: _btc"}
You have the URL formatted wrong, or in such a way that the json data cannot be accessed..